# Gtk.Grid inside another grid not visible on window

Tags: c, gtk3, vala, elementary-os

I made a separate file for all the labels to be used in the main window called Labels.vala

Previously, I had created the labels inside the MainWindow.vala file, but now I wanted to make a separate file for the labels as the labels will change based on the location set by the user and that will make the code in the MainWindow.vala file too long.

This is the code inside the Labels.vala file:
[image]

Now, when I try to add this class to a grid inside the main window, it compiles with no errors but the labels are not displayed in the main window.

[image]

This is how I add the labels grid in the main window grid.

Link to source code: https://github.com/Suzie97/epoch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you're trying to attach an instance of the `Labels` class to the `MainWindow` grid, but you need to use the `Labels.labels_grid` property that it exposes.

```vala
grid.attach (labels.labels_grid, 0, 4, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Now it displays this error: 
The symbol `Widgets' could not be found
    private Epoch.Widgets.Labels labels;

This is a really common error and I don't understand why does this happen. Can you explain it to me??

Comment: Actually I hadn't specified the Labels file in the meson.build file. My bad hehe

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @RajdeepSingha. FYI, you might find it better to refactor the layout so that it displays a row of `Clock` widgets that include the face and label.

Comment: Yeah I figured had already figured that out. I have created a grid for each clock including the labels.